# OpenShift V3 vs. OpenShift V2

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift-origin

I'm searching for a main difference between OpenShift V3 and V2.
Is OpenShift V2 working like this?: https://www.openshift.com/walkthrough/how-it-works
And how are Docker and Kubernetes working in V3?

Can someone give me a clear explanation about the build-up of OpenShift V2 and V3

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a rather broadly asked question, so I will (and can) answer only in a rather broad manner.

There are a lot of key concepts that have changed. These are the most important ones and you'll need some time to get into it, but they are a big improvement to OpenShift v2.:

- Cartridges vs. Docker Containers
- Gears vs. Kubernetes Pods
- Broker vs. Kubernetes Master
- Release of [Red Hat Enterprise Linux Atomic
  Host](https://access.redhat.com/articles/rhel-atomic-getting-started)

When you'll study the links below you will understand, that (really exaggerated) OpenShift v3 has basically nothing to do with v2 besides the name, the logo and the PaaS focus. But it's still a great tool and IMO has set new standards in the PaaS-world. (No, I don't work for RedHat ;)

What's New:

https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/whats_new/overview.html
https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/architecture/overview.html

For starters; Docker & Kubernetes:

https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-v3-platform-combines-docker-kubernetes-atomic-and-more/

Pretty new:

[Creating a Kubernetes Cluster to Run Docker Formatted Container Images](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1353773)

EDIT 2016_06_30:
Sorry for necro'ing this old post, but I wanted to add this quick, fun and *very* informative video about Kubernetes: https://youtu.be/4ht22ReBjno

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I agree with you in general, but this question is rather broadly asked and therefore hard to answer in this kinda format. (Or just c&p'ed)

Comment: Very true - it might have been worth marking this question as too broad, but seeing as you have linked documents already, why not summarise the information here? Having a quick glance at some of the websites, I feel a lot of the text is just waffle or extra added wordiness. Just quote a few bits and bobs, explain them a bit, and leave the links in. At least that way we have some information here on StackOverflow for safe keeping ;)

Comment: There you have it (;

Comment: Thanks you, I know the question is broadly but everything was very unclear for me.

Comment: @Anonymous Here's another one: https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-v3-deep-dive-docker-kubernetes/